# iOS 13 only occasionally suggests a strong password after switching from previous textfield

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, passwords, uitextfield

I'm struggling with adding a strong password generation to a UITextField on iOS 13. It doesn't work for my main new password field at all despite of adding `textContentType` to `.newPassword`. However, it works for my confirm password field only if I select it after my main password field.
Here's the setup for these textfields, which happens in controller's `init`.

```
    valueTextfield.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28)
    valueTextfield.autocapitalizationType = .none
    valueTextfield.autocorrectionType = .no
    valueTextfield.textColor = .black
    valueTextfield.textAlignment = .center
    valueTextfield.borderStyle = .none
    valueTextfield.tintColor = .primary
    valueTextfield.sizeToFit()valueTextfield.textContentType = .newPassword
    valueTextfield.placeholder = "Password".localized

    confirmationTextField.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28)
    confirmationTextField.textColor = .black
    confirmationTextField.textAlignment = .center
    confirmationTextField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    confirmationTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    confirmationTextField.textContentType = .newPassword
    confirmationTextField.borderStyle = .none
    confirmationTextField.tintColor = .primary
    confirmationTextField.placeholder = "Confirm".localized
```

Even adding a textfield to a blank controller doesn't help. Is that an iOS 13 bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the way I want autogenerated password to work is not possible at this moment. 
For strong password suggestion to work, **username textfield should be on the same screen** as password textfield. 
This is bizarre, but after researching apps like Twitter I discovered that non of them have strong password suggestion for a single password textfield. It's unknown whether it's a bug or a feature.
I'll have to go with reimplementing this feature manually.

Comment: I have username (hidden behind scroll view), current password, new password and confirmation for new password. Their not very smart way of doing this generates strong password for first two password fields instead of last two `.newPassword` fields. Only troubles with heuristics like this.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have these 3 properties of `UITextField` to be set correctly for password autofill to work:

```
textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
textField.textContentType = .password
```

And most importantly, enable password autofilling: 
`Settings > Passwords & Accounts > AutoFill Passwords`

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately, this didn't help, If I have a single textfield in a controller, there is no chance to get the strong password suggestion

Comment: I guess you should also have `.textContentType = .username` on some textfield too.

Comment: I do have it in a controller that comes before this one in a navigation stack, but that doesn't help

Comment: I know that working with `textContentType` may get confusing sometimes. E.g. I had a problem when autofill didn't work on some device and did on others. Couldn't figure it out why. It turned out to be that if you change keyboard type, autofill may turn off.